# Sorting Infinite Scroll with Mongo and Mongoose

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

How do I sort mongo collections before calling find on them? I've tried indexing and sort but results still show out of order. Sort works but only sorts the results that find pulled, but I need to pull results already sorted in order by date.

```
 events = await Event.find({
          time: {
            $gte:new Date()
        },
          $and: [
            {
              active: true
            }
          ]
        })
          .sort("-time")
          .limit(limit)
          .skip(skip);
```

With limit 5 applied:

```
{
  "data": {
    "searchEvents": [
      {
        "date": "2018-10-22T05:00:00.000Z",
        "events": [
          {
            "eventname": "First",
            "time": "2018-10-22T05:00:00.000Z"
          },
          {
            "eventname": "Second",
            "time": "2018-10-22T05:00:00.000Z"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "date": "2018-10-23T05:00:00.000Z",
        "events": [
          {
            "eventname": "Third",
            "time": "2018-10-23T05:00:00.000Z"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "date": "2018-10-26T05:00:00.000Z",
        "events": [
          {
            "eventname": "Fourth",
            "time": "2018-10-26T05:00:00.000Z"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "date": "2018-10-26T06:00:00.000Z",
        "events": [
          {
            "eventname": "Fifth",
            "time": "2018-10-26T06:00:00.000Z"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**With limit 3: It only shows 3rd,4th,and 5th**

Index used:
**EventsSchema.index({ time: -1});**

**Further clarification**
Question clarification: I'm trying to sort the results of my infinite scroll. Basically Mongo pulls 10 docs and I sort those results, then when the user gets tot he bottom is does that again skipping the first 10. The trouble is, this isn't in order. If I want the data sorted by date. It currently brings back the top 10 results and sorts that by date AFTER finding based on 'natural order'. How can I make Mongo find based on date? *Please keep in mind index and sort() both sort after.

Comment: And what do your documents look like and what order are they being returned in from this query?

Comment: @JohnnyHK I've edited my question

Comment: Indexing is the right way to go here. Can you update the question with the index you tried?

Comment: @JohnnyHK done. I've tried both -1 and 1. Same result. Also to clarify date.events structure here. I get back a list of event and put them into the dates grouped. So ignore date as a fix.

Comment: What does your schema looks like?

Comment: Here's the schema class I'm using:https://pastebin.com/cJyKNvLb

Comment: If I could insert at a position in the db that would work also.

Comment: Your `time` field in the schema is defined as a `Date`, but it's a string in your docs. Those need to match.

Comment: @JohnnyHK the string in the doc represents an ISODATE. Am I wrong?

Comment: Looks like it's just a string. Is this how the document shows in the shell?

Comment: @JohnnyHK yes its a date.

Comment: This question is still pretty vague and confusing. Can you try and simplify this down to a [MCVE]?

Answer (score 0):

use mongoose-paginate

or

Query all results...
Sort and limit on those results.